# Golang - Handling situations that would require generic types

Tags: go

I wrote a sendError handler for my API that will accept a string and return a response to my HTTP server. Here's the function:

```
func sendError(code string, message string, trace error, status int) (Response) {
  body, err := json.Marshal(&struct{
    Code    string `json:"Code"`
    Message string `json:"Message"`
  }{
    Code: code,
    Message: message,
  })
  fmt.Println(trace)
  if err != nil {
    panic("Issue parsing an error msg?")
  }
  return Response{
    Body: string(body),
    StatusCode: status,
    Headers: map[string]string{
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  }
}
```

Pretty simple, right? However recently I've had to return more advanced message types. Basically a hashmap (or dictionary) of validation errors from my support library (https://godoc.org/github.com/go-ozzo/ozzo-validation#ValidateStruct). What I'm currently doing is:

```
err := account.Validate()
if err != nil {
  fmt.Println(err)
  message, err := json.Marshal(err)
  return sendError(
    "VALIDATION_ERROR", string(message), err, 400,
  ), nil
}
```

However, as you can tell that will basically return a response similar to:

```
{
    "Code": "VALIDATION_ERROR",
    "Message": "{\"Email\":\"must be a valid email address\"}"
}
```

The JSON that is marshaled is obviously serialized into the Message property in the response. I could easily add another parameter to handle a situation where a dictionary would be accepted and simply extend the error response to have the additional field (so it's all marshalled nearly). To make my sendError function more ergonomic and also to see if generics like this are possible. I'd like to change message to be a generic value ie. `interface{}` and on a conditional check decide to handle the dictionary or the string versions of the responses.

What would be the best/most appropriate approach in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use type `interface{}` for the message argument and Message field:

```
func sendError(code string, message interface{}, trace error, status int) (Response) {
  body, err := json.Marshal(&struct{
    Code    string      `json:"Code"`
    Message interface{} `json:"Message"`
  }{
    Code: code,
    Message: message,
  })
  fmt.Println(trace)
  if err != nil {
    panic("Issue parsing an error msg?")
  }
  return Response{
    Body: string(body),
    StatusCode: status,
    Headers: map[string]string{
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  }
}
```

With this change, the application can call the function with a `string` or any other value that can be marshaled to JSON. For example, call it like this:'

```
err := account.Validate()
if err != nil {
  fmt.Println(err)
  return sendError("VALIDATION_ERROR", err, err, 400), nil
}
```

(This snippet assumes that err marshals to JSON in a suitable way.  Based on info in the question, it looks like it does).

Comment: That was actually as easy as I thought it would be. Thanks a bunch.